# Kotlin : conditional deleting from s list of object

Tags: list, kotlin

I have a scenario where I am suppose to delete objects form a list of objects,
but only if:

- a given property of an object is NULL and occurs in the list more than once

To clarify with an example:

- `A("b", null)` should be deleted, because object with property name="b" occurs in A("b", 3)
- `A("c", null)` should remain, because it object with property name="c" occurs in the listonly once
- `A("d", null)` one occurrence should be deleted and one should stay

Thank you in advance.

```
class A(
    val name: String,
    val amount: Int?
)

    val itemList = mutableListOf<A>(
        A("a", 2),
        A("b", 3),
        A("b", null),
        A("c", null),
        A("d", null),
        A("d", null)
    )
```

Comment: hi, welcome to StackOverflow show some code what have you already try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution creates a new list instead of mutating the original one:

```kotlin
itemList
    .groupBy { it.name }
    .values
    .flatMap { nameGroup ->
        val (nullAmountSubgroup, notNullAmountSubgroup) = nameGroup.partition { it.amount == null }
        notNullAmountSubgroup.ifEmpty { listOf(nullAmountSubgroup.first()) }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure this is you desired output:

[image: output]

```
val l: List<A> = itemList
    .groupBy { it.name }
    .map {
        return@map it.value.firstOrNull { el -> el.amount != null } ?: it.value.first()
    }

l.forEach { println("${it.name}: ${it.amount}") }
```

Comment: this will filter out all same-named items, which occurs in the list more than once (even if  their amount is not null)

Comment: Yeah, Michael's commented right. This did distinct on it as well.